# Why doesn't the concept of open ball imply a metric in the usual topology?

Tags: general-topology

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_(mathematics)#Topological_balls)

> [One may talk about balls in any topological space X, not necessarily induced by a metric.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_(mathematics)#Topological_balls)

However, in the usual topology on R has as basis the set of all open balls, and open balls are defined as

$$B(p;r) =\{x\in X \;\vert\;d(x,p)<r\}$$

Aren't $d$ and $r$ distances, implicitly implying that a metric has been defined? In other words, how can this standard or usual topology in, for instance $\mathbb R^3,$ be properly defined as open balls without acknowledging the use of a metric?

If, on the other hand, the topology is defined as [neighborhoods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_(mathematics)), the problem may not be there...

Comment: Yes, $d$ is a distance and $r$ is a real number. And no, there is no concept of a ball outside of the metric world.

Comment: @freakish How is the quote from Wikipedia interpretable, then?

Comment: I don't know why you've been downvoted, so I upvote to counter this. The question does not deserve a downvote.

Comment: there's lots of naughty stuff on Wikipedia. still a great bargain for the price.

Comment: One point that is not stated clearly enough in the present answers: just because one induced topology of $X$ is metrizable (via the homeomorphism to Euclidean space) doesn't mean that all of $X$ is metrizable.

Comment: Wikipedia is clear, as long as you copy the whole thing, and do not present it out of context.  An (open or closed) n-dimensional topological ball of X is any subset of X which is homeomorphic to an (open or closed) Euclidean n-ball. (in particular, the interior of the unit square is a topological ball. The whole n-Euclidean space is a topological ball. There are many more examples.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a [metric topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#topological_properties): it is induced by a metric, in the sense that it is the coarsest topology on $\mathbb R$ making the euclidian metric $d:\mathbb R \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R_{+}$ continuous.

There are topologies not induced by metrics, and worse there are some that are not [metrizable](https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Metrizable_space). For example, there is a topology on $\mathbb R$ that consists of itself and the empty set. This is not induced by any metric.

Comment: Can you say that if the concept of an open ball is brought into the definition of a topology, there is necessarily a metric defined? Is it the same for n-hoods?

Comment: Yeah, i would say that "ball" is reserved for metric spaces. Neighborhoods are not so. Those are choices of open sets containing a point.

Answer (score 2):

> Aren't $d$ and $r$ distances, implicitly implying that a metric has been defined?

Yes.

> In other words, how can this standard or usual topology in, for instance $\mathbb R^3,$ be properly defined as open balls without acknowledging the use of a metric?

That cannot be done. You need the concept of a metric to define a ball. But that does not necessarily mean that $X$ has to be a metric space.

Actually if you read the wiki article to the end it should be clearer:

> One may talk about balls in any topological space X, not necessarily induced by a metric. An (open or closed) n-dimensional topological ball of X is any subset of X which is homeomorphic to an (open or closed) Euclidean n-ball. Topological n-balls are important in combinatorial topology, as the building blocks of cell complexes.

The notion of a ball **does not** exist outside of the metric world. You have to touch it at some point. What wiki is saying is that there is a thing called a topological ball which is simply a subset of a topological space that is homeomorphic to an Euclidean ball. But for that you still need a notion of a (Euclidean) metric.

For example consider

$$f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^2$$
$$f(t)=(\sin(t), \cos(t))$$

The image of $f$ is an arc (a piece of a circle). This function is a homeomorphism so the image $f([0,1])$ is a topological closed ball (because $[0,1]$ is a ball in $\mathbb{R}$) even though it is not a ball (because it is a subset of the standard sphere $S^1$).